# Testing properties of mapping given graph

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry

Suppose we are given a graph of a mapping (in $\Bbb R^2$ or $\Bbb R^3$) and we want to test graphically if it is a graph of a function, if it is one-to-one and if it is onto.

- $\Bbb R^2$ : $$\begin{align} 
  \text{Function} & \iff \text{all lines parallel to the y-axis intersect the graph no more than once}.\\
  \text{one-to-one}& \iff \text{all lines parallel to the x-axis intersect the graph no more than once.}\\
  \text{onto}& \iff \text{all lines parallel to the x-axis intersect the graph at least once.}\\
  \end{align}$$

---

- $\Bbb R^3$ : $$\begin{align} 
  \text{Function} & \iff \text{all lines parallel to the z-axis intersect the graph no more than once}.\\
  \text{one-to-one}& \iff \text{all planes parallel to the xy-plane intersect the graph no more than once.}\\
  \text{onto}& \iff \text{all planes parallel to the xy-plane intersect the graph at least once.}\\
  \end{align}$$

Are these methods correct?

Answer (score -2):

In the case of Function, change "no more than once" to "exactly once" (assuming the function is defined on all of $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^2$ respectively.

Comment: Why the downvotes?